# MySQL: Very slow query on a huge table with order by timestamp (despite of having indexes)…

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a `sync_log_lines` table with millions of records.

```
CREATE TABLE `sync_log_lines` (
  `uuid` char(36) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `sync_log_uuid` char(36) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `exception_time` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `exception_message` mediumtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `exception_file` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `exception_line` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `failure_reason` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `csv_file_row_count` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `csv_file_row_sequence` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `csv_file_row_content` mediumtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `csv_file_source` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`uuid`),
  KEY `sync_log_lines_sync_log_uuid_index` (`sync_log_uuid`),
  KEY `sync_log_lines_exception_time_index` (`exception_time`),
  CONSTRAINT `sync_log_lines_sync_log_uuid_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`sync_log_uuid`) REFERENCES `sync_logs` (`uuid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

A single "sync" operation may insert 150k of records into this table. Each record in `sync_log_lines` is a single CSV row that failed to be inserted or updated in it's dedicated table.

So below query I use may escalate quickly.

```
select `uuid`, `sync_log_uuid`, `exception_time`, `exception_message`, `failure_reason`, `csv_file_row_count`, `csv_file_row_sequence`, `csv_file_row_content` 
from `sync_log_lines` 
where `sync_log_uuid` = '56b0a3b1-dab4-4343-9f9b-a2a8f075c21a' 
order by `exception_time` desc 
limit 100 offset 6000;
```

There's overall amount of ~150k records where `sync_log_uuid` = `56b0a3b1-dab4-4343-9f9b-a2a8f075c21a`. Without `order by` it takes milliseconds to give me first `100` records.

When I add `order by` as presented above it slows down to 30-45 seconds.

I know, I know. I did a research and I fully understand that:

> when I run query without ORDER BY - LIMIT 100, it works perfectly - it
>   stops query after first 100 records, **any** 100 records

but

> when I add ORDER BY then MySQL first sends **all records** to temporary
>   table, **then sorts** it and then returns to me **100 correct records**

It absolutely makes sense. On huge dataset it works as expected. But I've reached to the point where I don't know how to optimise it. I cannot narrow down the dates (`exception_time`) since all `log lines` for that `UUID` are inserted within 2 hrs - this is the approx. sync time.

My query is used as part of the pagination and sometimes there is a case where user has to see page **212 (!)** of this particular sync.

Is there any space for improvement? A composite index? Anything else?

Comment: [pagination](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination), maybe use the exception_time as the starting point `WHERE exception_time > {prev value} LIMIT 100`

Answer (score 3):

Create 1 index on both sync_log_uuid and exception_time.

```
CREATE INDEX my_index ON sync_log_lines (sync_log_uuid, exception_time);
```

Finding the first 100 records is quickly to do for MySQL if you do not ORDER BY, because it can just return the first 100 records it finds.

In case you order by exception_time MySQL has to read all the records where sync_log_uuid = '56b0a3b1-dab4-4343-9f9b-a2a8f075c21a' to to determine which ones are the first 100.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use composite index is also known as a multiple-column index. It will give better performance. As mention into above answer to create index
http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-index/mysql-composite-index/